# How to add event listener to window

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird-addon

In my addon I have a menu command that opens the xul Options panel for my addon.  That xul window has no javascript of its own.

However, since the main script opens the panel, how can the main script know when the user clicks Okay in that window and the data is submitted?  I want to know when the submit event fires so I can check the preferences that were set in the Options window.

Basically, I want to run a function when the window gets submitted, but I want to do everything from the main addon script.

Here is what I have right now.

```
function OpenPrefsPanel(){
    var prefpanel = window.openDialog("chrome://myaddon/content/options.xul", "", "centerscreen,chrome,modal");
    prefpanel.addEventListener("submit", function(e){  doSomething(); },false );
},
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that if the window you are opening is not the same domain

Comment: well, both windows are from my own addon - does that mean they are the same domain?

Comment: Just FYI: I have not looked at options for Thunderbird, but in Firefox the `features` specified for options windows are; `'chrome,titlebar,toolbar,centerscreen,modal'`.

Comment: You have the window object, `prefPanel`, why not just add a listener for the `close` event? Or an observer on the preferences for your add-on?

Comment: In these docs, there is no `close` event: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener

Comment: oooh!  An observer on the preferences is better.  Good idea!  If you post a sample I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll write it up.  Although there are docs with examples

Comment: I guess you'd have to add the event listener to the object that emits the submit event - which isn't the window

Comment: Here's the docs for the observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#Using_preference_observers

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. I already had it open (I've previously looked at adding a preferences observer to one of my Firefox extensions, but always just used other methodologies). I was busy testing other events and looking at what other ways I've handled this in the past (e.g. [ondialogaccept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/ondialogaccept)).  With a preference observer you get called for every change, which may, or may not, be your desire (and was not explicitly what your questions stated).

Comment: Yeah; maybe I should change the question title.  Looks like adding an observer is a bit involved and I'm feeling really lazy.  Seems like there is no way to do this with an event listener anyway.

Comment: Well, you could certainly just listen for the dialog window to close (i.e. [nsIWindowMediatorListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator#addListener())).

Comment: Ummm.... After this discussion, it looks like we all missed: You are using [`window.openDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/openDialog) with the `modal` `feature` specified.  That means that it is a modal window and execution of your code stops until the window is closed (just tested/confirmed on Firefox with a modal *options.xul*).  There is no need to listen for anything. All the options will have been changed by the time you reach the next line of code.  I guess we are all just so used to asynchronous that we were not thinking about this.

Comment: Do you still need a different solution, or does this being blocking/modal/synchronous solve your problem? Note: in Firefox this is only modal wrt. a single window (i.e. you can interact with other windows if you have more that one open).

Answer (score 0):

As it is currently, your events never fire because you are passing [`'modal'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Features_requiring_privileges) with the [`windowFeatures` string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features).  This makes the execution of [`window.openDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/openDialog) modal and blocking (synchronous).  Thus, the first line after your `window.openDialog()` will only execute after the user has either clicked on "OK", or "Cancel". As a result, your `prefpanel.addEventListener()` is executed after the window is already closed/closing.  The [MDN documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/openDialog):

> The call to `openDialog()` returns immediately. If you want the call to block until the user has closed the dialog, supply modal as a `windowFeatures` parameter. Note that this also means the user won't be able to interact with the opener window until he closes the modal dialog.

You could choose to change how you open the dialog so that it is not modal:

```
var prefpanel = window.openDialog("chrome://myaddon/content/options.xul", ""
                                  , "centerscreen,chrome");
```

In that case, you could use the following to get any of the `unload`, `dialogaccept`, or `dialogcancel` events (tested in Firefox 51.0a2):

```
var prefpanel = window.openDialog("chrome://myaddon/content/options.xul", ""
                                  , "centerscreen,chrome");
prefpanel.addEventListener('load',optionsLoaded,true);
function optionsLoaded(){
    console.log('Options Window Loaded');
    //unload also fires prior to the load event, so add listener here in load handler:
    prefpanel.addEventListener('unload',optionsUnload,true);
    prefpanel.addEventListener('dialogaccept',dialogAccept,true);
    prefpanel.addEventListener('dialogcancel',dialogCancel,true);
}
function optionsUnload(){
    console.log('Options Window UNLOAD');
}
function dialogAccept(){
    console.log('Options Window dialogAccept');
}
function dialogCancel(){
    console.log('Options Window dialogCancel');
}
```

Note: At least in Firefox, the option dialogs are normally opened with the following `windowFeatures`: `'chrome,titlebar,toolbar,centerscreen,modal'`.

However, given that your options dialog can be opened from the Add-ons Manager, you should probably implement some additional method for you to be notified that your options have changed.  This could be a [preference observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#Using_preference_observers), or have a small amount of JavaScript included with your *options.xul*. For instance, the [`<prefwindow>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/prefwindow) element has [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/prefwindow#Attributes) which could be used to add code which is executed upon the user clicking "OK" ([`ondialogaccept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/prefwindow#a-ondialogaccept)), or "Cancel" ([`ondialogcancel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/prefwindow#a-ondialogcancel). Doing so with those attributes could be done with only minor changes to your *options.xul* file. While using `addEventListener()` is generally preferable, using the attributes is can be a reasonable choice.